# Simple present, present perfect or simple past?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple, present-simple

Question 1.

> A: How long have you lived there?
>
> B: I **have lived** there all my life.

For B, why we can't use *"live"* instead of Present Perfect *"have lived"*? 
Present simple suggests that person B has live there all his life and will probably live there the rest of his life.

Question 2.

> A: Have you ever studied any other languages?
>
> B: Yes, I **learnt** German for two years when I was at school.

For B, why can't we use *"have learnt"* instead of Simple Past "*learnt*"?

Answer (score 1):

Question A: How long have you lived there? B: I have lived there all my life.

1) You use the present perfect in /I have lived there all my life/ because **at the time of speaking your proposition began in the past and it is still true in the present**. You have to imagine the timeline when using verbs in English. Past___Present____Future = the Timeline. If something began in the past and is still true, you need PP.

**Simple present is for general propositions that are true in the present at time of speaking:** I live in Paris. I live my life to the fullest.

2) Have you ever studied any other languages? B: Yes, I learnt German for two years when I was at school.

Yes, I **studied** [not the verb learn here] German for two years when I was at school.

The reason: when I **was at** school. **At the time of speaking, you are no longer in school**. The condition of being at school is over and finished.

NB: **I prefer** /to study a language/ than /to learn a language/here. But that is a separate discussion.

Comment: I understand the latter but not the former. What's the difference between "I have lived there all my life" and "I live there all my life", both are true in the present at the time of speaking.

Comment: I told you: ***If something STARTS in the past and is still true at the time of speaking, you cannot use the simple present to express it.*** /***How long***/ implies an action or attitude that started in the past. (Unless you want to use it as a future). ***Any action or attitude that begins in the past (How long, Since when etc.) cannot be expressed by a verb in the present simple.*** The possibilities are: How long DID you live, How long HAVE you lived, How long HAVE YOU BEEN LIVING. All actions that started in the past. I live in Oslo is now, and does not mention any past.

Comment: @English Guy - David What an odd name for someone asking questions here. :) Just saying...

Comment: Just for confirmation, Simple Present Tense is something that starts and ends constantly and habitually over a period of time and yet continues at the time of speaking. But present perfect is something that starts and continues (but no ends) at the time of speaking. And, many thanks for the analytical explanation you provided.

Comment: No, not starts and ends constantly. Simple Present describes a situation or action that ***just is*** in the present.  No, PP does not END at the time of speaking. It starts in the past and continues to be true at the time of speaking. I have lived in Oslo for two years (implies: I still live there).

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. If the sentence were "John goes to the badminton court every Sunday", this implies that John goes to the badminton court in probably the morning and leaves probably in the afternoon, and we also know that John still continues going to the court every Sunday. I don't really grasp what you mean by "just is in the present". Apologies if this is irritating you a whole lot.

Comment: The present simple just expresses a general proposition and that may include a day or time. Its truthfulness or lack thereof is not related to adverbial phrases. In that sense: / She drinks tea every day/ and /She drinks tea/ both express a general proposition that applies to her. I was contrasting the SP to the PP for your purposes. I was not giving a complete overview of the SP.

Comment: I believe both tenses share the same rule of something having started from the past, innit? As I understand, "I live there all my life" = I live there when I was a baby then a teenager and now an adult, never have I left the place and I'm still living there. "I have lived there all my life" = we don't know when we have started living there but we are still living there.  Still, what difference does it make?

Comment: ***/I live there all my life/ is simply not grammatical in English under any circumstances***. I  have explained enough and your repetition of the ungrammatical sentence is annoying me. You have managed to do that. Let another English speaker tell you. Simple present sentences have no relationship to the past.

Comment: One last point: People come here and ask questions that any educated native speaker should be able to answer. And when they are presented with the very basic fact about their question, something any native speaker knows (even probably the unschooled), they keep repeating their misconception which brought them here in the first place! It's hard to fathom.

Comment: Are you by any chance a native speaker of German? (I ask because the forms you 'want' to use are those which are grammatical in German.) You should be aware that although the English and German perfect are almost identical in *form*, their *uses* are markedly different. The presence in English of an explicit progressive form means that we 'divide up' the uses of simple, progressive and perfect forms in ways which are not available to speakers of German.

Comment: @Lambie Trying to overcome a questioner's preconceptions is often very frustrating! --not least because it's so difficult to *recognize* preconceptions which differ so greatly from one's own. Your consolation should be that it's just as frustrating for the questioner, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @StoneyB Perhaps so but my attitude when asking a question to those whom I believe presumably know more about the issue is take what they say and ponder it and not keep repeating my original propositions. :)

Comment: Oh! Is it because of the time expression "all my life"? I looked on web and you can use something like "I live in the United Kingdom" but not "I live in the United Kingdom all my life". I probably was heavily baffled because the sentence isn't constructed with the preposition "for", and I'm so used to the prepositions being around all the time. "I have lived in the United Kingdom for all my life" sounds best to me.

Comment: No, it is not because of /all my life/. You can google the use of FOR and SINCE in English grammar. None take the present and they all take the PP.